# MSE and cross validation score drastically differ from residuals in scale for a GLM

Tags: r, regression, glm, cross-validation, mse

I have encountered something which I believe is critical and will be of use for people in the future when fitting and analyzing GLM in R. The response in my dataset is a variable of frequency data and the set contains 1762 observations. I have fitted a Negative Binomial-model (named `nb1`) with the command `glm.nb` and I wish to estimate how well the model predicts the data.

For starters - when applying the command `residuals.glm` (same result if I apply command `residuals`) I get

```
head(residuals.glm(nb1))
     1          2          3          4          5          6 
-1.1630170  2.9662854  2.0234981  0.1104864 -0.6636815  0.5303713
```

which is reasonable and is in line with the diagnostic graphs.

This is where it becomes confusing.
When calculating residuals manually I get

```
head(y - fitted(nb1))
      1           2           3           4           5           6 
-35.4970139  28.2611731  10.0475912   0.2914508 -10.0584696   2.4523959
```

Calculating the MSE with the command residuals I get

```
mean(residuals(nb1)^2)
[1] 1.061085
```

while calculating the MSE manually I get

```
mean((y - fitted(nb1))^2)
[1] 4138.733
```

which is basically the same value as when I apply LOOCV (leave-one-out cross validation)

```
loocvnb <- cv.glm(dfg, nb1, data=dfg), K=1764)
$delta
[1] 4352.700 4352.614
```

The default function for the vector `delta` in LOOCV is MSE.

Why is it that the MSE for the manually omitted case and for LOOCV is so drastically different from when applying the function `residuals`?

Comment: But how do i get the same value manually compared to the residuals-command?

Comment: Allright. So how can i justify such large values for the delta from cv.glm?

Comment: Spoke to my counsel, since nb-models are more flexible they may take som extreme outliers into account which leads to a higher MSE. Thank you for your help, Zheyuan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Residuals returned by `residuals.glm` are by default deviance residuals. When you do `y - fitted(nb1)` you refer to raw residuals. Use

```
residuals.glm(nb1, type = "response")
```